# How can I use env variables in fastlane for creating the template

Tags: gitlab-ci, fastlane

I have build and distributed my iOS app using fastlane, for that I have created script in fast file, so now I want pass the env variable in this script for creating the template, this same template I can use my other iOS apps as well, so how can I pass env variables in my fastlane script?

Answer (score 16):

`Fastfile` and Co are just Ruby code, so you can use `ENV['XYZ']` to access any environment variables.

To set environment variables, there are multiple options in fastlane. Some are described at https://docs.fastlane.tools/advanced/other/#environment-variables 
Fastlane also supports `dotenv` to set environment variables via files: https://docs.fastlane.tools/best-practices/keys/#dotenv

Comment: Special thanks for that "just Ruby code" part.